# Julia drawing from standard normal distribution

Tags: performance, random, julia, normal-distribution, juno-ide

I need to draw 53000000 observations from a standard normal distribution. My current code takes a long time to run in Julia (in fact, it's been running for the past twenty minutes) and I'm wondering if there's anything I can do to speed it up. Here's what I tried:

```
using Distributions
d = Normal()
shock = rand(d, 1, 53000000)
```

The code works instantaneously when I execute it in REPL (I am working in Juno/Atom), but lags at this point (drawing from the standard normal) when I step through using the debugger. So I think the debugger may be the real culprit here.

Comment: It runs almost instantly for me, you might need to provide more information (hardware, version, etc.)

Comment: To provide that info, type `versioninfo()` at the `julia> ` prompt and copy it here.

Comment: Huh. I restarted Julia and it was instantaneous! Maybe this question should be closed/deleted since I can't replicate the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, after a few more runs, the code is again hanging at the point where I draw from the standard normal. Here's my versioninfo(): 

Julia Version 1.3.1
Commit 2d5741174c (2019-12-30 21:36 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Windows (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.1 (ORCJIT, skylake)
Environment:
  JULIA_EDITOR = "C:\Users\Anshu\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.43.0\atom.exe"  -a
  JULIA_NUM_THREADS = 2

Comment: Note that you do not need `Distributions` to sample from a standard normal, a simple `randn` would suffice.

Comment: Alternatively (if your task allows it), you can preallocate a smaller block (say, of size 10000, or ideally a page full), and resample into it repeatedly using the in-place `randn!`.

Comment: Minor note: `rand(d, 1, N)` produces a matrix of size 1xN. If you intended to produce a vector, you would write `rand(d, N)`. (I'm just mentioning this because I've seen the above pattern a lot among people coming from Matlab.)

Comment: Why do you actually need that huge vector? You can create the random numbers out of thin air at the moment you need to use them in a reproducible way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that the 1/2 gig of memory used by the allocation of the variable `shock` is sometimes causing swapping when the debugger is loaded.

Try running this to see, in the debugger:

```
using Distributions, Base.Sys

println("Free memory is $(Int(Sys.free_memory()))")
d = Normal()
shock = rand(d, 1, 53000000)
println("shock uses $(sizeof(shock)) bytes.")
println("Free memory is $(Int(Sys.free_memory()))")
```

Are you close to out of memory in gigs?

Comment: I get "Free memory is 1525129216" after running this, but also the "shock = " step didn't hang at all this time. Maybe I was just running low on memory for unrelated reasons.